# Why is it possible to move from a field of an immutable struct?

Tags: rust

If an instance of a struct is not declared as `mut`, why it is still possible to move from a field of the struct? (at the same time it is not possible to move from an item of a vector even if the vector is declared as `mut`).
Here is an example based on the one from the rust book:

```
#![allow(unused_variables)]

struct User {
    username: String,
    email: String,
    sign_in_count: u64,
    active: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let user1 = User {
        email: String::from("a@b.com"),
        username: String::from("one123"),
        active: true,
        sign_in_count: 1
    };
    let s = user1.email;
    println!("{0}", user1.email);
}
```

The issue is that the value from the field has been moved.

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `user1.email`
  --> src/main.rs:19:21
   |
18 |     let s = user1.email;
   |             ----------- value moved here
19 |     println!("{0}", user1.email);
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
   |
```

Why is that allowed? What is the motivation? Looks like const-correctness is broken for structs.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any const-correctness broken, since your code doesn't compile. Also, moving in Rust means "taking ownership", not "mutating". Since ownership is exclusive, there is no harm in giving ownership without requiring mutability (at the price that you won't own anymore the data, then).

Comment: The code does not compile, but the error is that the value has been moved: not the attempt to move from a field of an immutable instance. If the `println!` used other fields of the instance, the movement from the email field was perfectly valid.

Comment: Moving a field just implies a change of ownership, *not mutation* (indeed, nothing was changed). What makes you think moving and mutation are related in the first place?

Comment: Well, my intuition is that the const bindings should be reference-transparent. Obviously the instance after changing ownership of one of its fields is not _equal_ to the "original object". But OK, rust allows to do that and apparently prohibits any way to "check" the difference between the original and its modified version (it is not possible to pass such an object outside of the current scope).

Comment: Referencial transparency is impossible in non-pure languages (and Rust is not a pure language — think of `let a = println!("hello");`, this binding is never reference-transparent). Besides, there is one catch in what you said: there is *no more instance* of the variable after one of its fields was moved. Taking ownership does not mean replacing with something new, which is why @tadman uses the word "destroyed" for this operation. You could, in theory, replace the field when moving it, but that would require having a mutable variable, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rust mutability means something more specific than "can't be changed", it means it can't be altered in its current form.

There are cases where you're not modifying it per-se, you're ripping it apart into its constituent elements, in which case the original has not been modified, it has been destroyed.

What you're doing here is asking to remove the `email` property from that record, which Rust will gladly do for you, though at the expense of destroying the structure that property came from.

Once you start the process of dismantling an object, there is no going back. To avoid this you either make a copy, or use a reference.

```rust
let s = &user1.email;
println!("{0}", s); // Perfectly valid
println!("{0}", &user1.email); // Still valid, not affected

let t = user1.email.clone();
println!("{0}", t); // Independent copy
println!("{0}", &user1.email); // Still valid, not affected
```

Note, the only reason Rust tries to move this property is because it can. If you're working with a reference to that type you can't move anything, everything is automatically a reference, including `user1.email`.

It is often the case in Rust that a function will receive an argument that contains a lot of information that needs to be moved into other locations. The most efficient way to do this is to often dismantle the argument given and move the parts into their desired locations.

Comment: Doesn't the removal of the email property mean the altering of the instance? On the other hand it looks like it is possible to move from a field only for a "by-value" instance: via a reference everything looks fine in terms of const-correctness.

Comment: If Rust is going to move a property, it has already destroyed the source. That's why you can't use `user1` later on, it's already dead. You can and probably should use references or copies if you want to preserve the original value.

Comment: Indeed, an attempt to pass the instance outside of the current scope leads to the compilation error "value partially moved here". OK, things are more clear for me now. Thank you!

Comment: Clarification: The entire `user1` value isn't destroyed, it has been _partially_ moved. You can continue to move other values from it (e.g. you can move `user1.username` after moving `user1.email`).

Comment: @cdhowie A good distinction. What I mean is that the `user1` element itself has been destroyed, or at least split into pieces but the constituent parts can still be utilized. If they aren't moved, they're dropped.

Comment: Note that it's not true that, if `user1` is a reference to a struct, so will `user1.email` by default. See [this counter-example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d9944158e72c19a5aa9daf44fc83cda), and see that [it compiles if you explicitly add the `&`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=312732e6e8fa7791bb11e9f8986d3468).